# Passing a json file as a parameter to a method

Tags: c#, json.net

I am learning how to work with json data using Newtonsoft.Json.

I stored my valid json file in a folder in my console application and calling 
a method that will process the json file.

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IEnumerable<IEnumerable<string>> result;
            string pathToFile = @"C:\DevelopmentJson\ConsoleApp1\File\my_test.json";

            MyReader objReader = new MyReader();
            result = objReader.Export(pathToFile).ToList();

            Console.WriteLine("Hello");
        }
```

Here is the method within my class that is been called.

```
        public IEnumerable<IEnumerable<string>> Export(string json)
        {
            var document = JToken.Parse(json);

            var data = new List<List<string>>();
            .....
            return data;
        }
```

I am beginning to feel I cannot use a pathToFile as a path to my json file.

I started to get the error message below on this line [var document = JToken.Parse(json);]

```
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: 
'Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: C. Path '', line 0, position 0.'
```

How do I resolve this error message?

Comment: No one can help you without having an actual json, please share it. Another point is that question title and actual question looks quite different

Comment: can you post your json data? if it is not too big? or at lease first few lines.

Comment: You're not actually parsing the file, you're parsing the path.

Comment: https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ReadJson.htm

Comment: How do I pass the file? I will post json soon. The json is valid. I think passing the file is the problem

Comment: I posted my json file

Answer (score 1):

The [Newtonsoft Json.NET documentation](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Introduction.htm) has two examples showing how to [deserialize JSON from a file](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeWithJsonSerializerFromFile.htm). Below are both examples with minor modifications to help integrate with your code.

**Option 1. Reading JSON data via JsonConvert**

```
var pathToFile = @"C:\DevelopmentJson\ConsoleApp1\File\my_test.json";

// read file into a string and deserialize JSON to a type
var dataFromJsonConvert = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyData>(File.ReadAllText(pathToFile));

// dataFromJsonConvert now holds your JSON data from file
```

**Option 2. Reading JSON data via JsonSerializer**

```
var pathToFile = @"C:\DevelopmentJson\ConsoleApp1\File\my_test.json";

// deserialize JSON directly from a file
using (StreamReader file = File.OpenText(pathToFile))
{
    var serializer = new JsonSerializer();
    var dataFromJsonSerializer = (IEnumerable<IEnumerable<string>>)serializer.Deserialize(file, typeof(MyData));

    // dataFromJsonSerializer now holds your JSON data from file
}
```

**Example demonstrating how to utilize answer**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var pathToFile = "C:\DevelopmentJson\ConsoleApp1\File\my_test.json";

    var fileJsonRaw = File.ReadAllText(pathToFile))

    var objReader = new MyReader();
    var fileJsonParsed = objReader.Export(fileJsonRaw).ToList();

    Console.WriteLine("Hello");
}

public MyData Export(string json)
{
    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyData>(json);
}
```

**Classes generated from your JSON data**

The classes below were generated from your sample JSON. These classes are used within answer to demonstrate a complete solution.

```
public partial class MyData
{
    [JsonProperty("UpdatedDay")]
    public string UpdatedDay { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("UpdatedUser")]
    public string UpdatedUser { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("solution")]
    public Solution[] Solution { get; set; }
}

public partial class Solution
{
    [JsonProperty("title")]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("description")]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("fields")]
    public Field[] Fields { get; set; }
}

public partial class Field
{
    [JsonProperty("firstname")]
    public string Firstname { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("lastiname", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public string Lastiname { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("required")]
    public bool FieldRequired { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("lastname", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public string Lastname { get; set; }
}
```

**Note**: The following using statements are necessary.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Globalization;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Converters;
```

Comment: When I try to call the export method passing the dataFromJsonSerializer as a string, I got this error cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>>' to 'string' . My json file is valid. it is just too big

Comment: It's not too big. `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<string>>` just isn't the right type for you.

Comment: @user2320476 you should use the code from one of the options within my answer within the `Export` method. I'll update my answer to illustrate.

Comment: @user2320476 answer updated with an example of how to utilize within your code.

Comment: @Joelius without seeing the contents of the JSON file we can't confirm it is, or is not, the correct type. That's why I added a note to my answer indicating the assumption of type compatibility with JSON content.

Comment: They posted the json but removed it a bit later on again. Based on the posted json (see the questions edit history) and the error they get, I feel comfortable saying that `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<string>>` is probably not the right type for them.

Comment: @Joelius thanks for the tip. You are correct, `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<string>>` will not work.

Answer (score 0):

[JToken.Parse](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_Parse.htm) doesn't take a path, it takes the actual json string.

You can get the contents of the file with [`File.ReadAllText`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readalltext).

Something like this (checks etc omitted):

```cs
public IEnumerable<IEnumerable<string>> Export(string path)
{
    string json = File.ReadAllText(path);
    var document = JToken.Parse(json);

    var data = new List<List<string>>();
    .....
    return data;
}
```

Note that there are better ways of parsing a file with json.net. For more info read [this](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ReadJson.htm).